# Token jwt not expired

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt

The token (for testing) I make it last only 60 seconds but it seems to never expire. Passing it the bearer on Postman, the getInfo route keeps giving me a response as if the token were still valid even after 60 seconds. What could I have done wrong?

I have this folders tree:

```
├── app.js
├── node_modules
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
├── private
│   ├── private.key
│   └── public.key
├── public
│   ├── html
│   │   └── cover.html
│   └── images
│       ├── logo-w.png
│       └── logo.png
├── request.http
├── src
│   ├── auth
│   │   ├── authService.js
│   │   └── tokenManager.js
│   ├── middleware
│   │   └── authMiddleware.js
│   └── routes
│       ├── auth.js
│       └── info.js
```

I have different files but the main file is app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
const fs = require('fs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

require('dotenv').config();

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(express.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/html", "cover.html"));
});

const infoRoute = require("./src/routes/info");
const authRoute = require("./src/routes/auth");

app.use("/info", infoRoute);
app.use("/auth", authRoute);

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server Is Running On Port", port);
});
```

in my authService.js I mocked a simple login for testing:

```
const { issueJWT, issueRefreshToken } = require('./tokenManager');
const users = [{ id: 1, username: 'test', password: 'password' }];

const login = (username, password) => {
  const user = users.find(u => u.username === username && u.password === password);
  if (!user) throw new Error('Credentials not valid');

  const tokenObject = issueJWT(user);
  const refreshToken = issueRefreshToken(user);
  return {
    ...tokenObject,
    refreshToken: refreshToken
  };
};

module.exports = { login };
```

in my tokenManager.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const PRIV_KEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../private/private.key'), 'utf8');

const issueJWT = (user) => {
  const expiresIn = 60;
  const payload = {
    sub: user.id,
    iat: Date.now(),
  };
  const signedToken = jwt.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, { expiresIn: expiresIn, algorithm: 'RS256' });
  return {
    token: "Bearer " + signedToken,
    expires: expiresIn
  };
};

const issueRefreshToken = (user) => {
  const expiresIn = '7d';
  const payload = {
    sub: user.id,
    iat: Date.now(),
  };
  const refreshToken = jwt.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, { expiresIn: expiresIn, algorithm: 'RS256' });
  return refreshToken;
};

module.exports = { issueJWT, issueRefreshToken };
```

and in my authMiddleware.js

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const PUB_KEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../private/public.key'), 'utf8');

const authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (authHeader) {
    const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

    jwt.verify(token, PUB_KEY, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, (err, user) => {
      if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
      req.user = user;
      next();
    });
  } else {
    res.sendStatus(401);
  }
};

module.exports = { authenticateJWT };
```

auth.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { login } = require('../auth/authService');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { issueJWT } = require('../auth/tokenManager');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const PUB_KEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../private/public.key'), 'utf8');

// Endpoint per il login
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const { token, expires, refreshToken } = login(username, password); // Aggiunto refreshToken
    res.json({
      success: true,
      token: token,
      expiresIn: expires,
      refreshToken: refreshToken // Inviato il refreshToken nella risposta
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
});

// Endpoint per il rinnovo del token
router.post('/refreshToken', (req, res) => {
  const { refreshToken } = req.body;

  if (!refreshToken) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Refresh Token richiesto" });
  }

  try {
    const payload = jwt.verify(refreshToken, PUB_KEY, { algorithms: ['RS256'] });

    // Aggiungi qui la logica per verificare che il refresh token sia ancora valido, per esempio controllando nel tuo database

    const user = { id: payload.sub }; // Assumi che tu possa ottenere l'utente in base al sub nel payload
    const newTokenObject = issueJWT(user);
    res.json({
      success: true,
      token: newTokenObject.token,
      expiresIn: newTokenObject.expires
    });

  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "Refresh Token non valido" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

and finally in my info.js (protected area)

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { authenticateJWT } = require('../middleware/authMiddleware');

router.get('/getInfo', authenticateJWT, (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: 'Protected area' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Quick tip, put the problem statement at the top of the question to provide some context and to save people having to scroll through hundreds of lines of code to understand what you're asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change three parts in your code.

#### #1 issueJWT()

In `./src/auth/tokenManager.js`

```js
const issueJWT = (user) => {
    const expiresIn = 60; // 60 seconds
    const payload = {
        sub: user.id,
        iat: Date.now(),
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + expiresIn // exp is in seconds since Unix epoch
    };
    const signedToken = jwt.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
    return {
        token: signedToken,
        expires: expiresIn
    };
};
```

The "Bearer" is not nessaray

From

```
    token: "Bearer " + signedToken,
```

To

```
    token: signedToken,
```

And `payload.exp` need to add from now() with 60 seconds

#### #2 authenticateJWT()

In `./src/middleware/authMiddleware.js`

```js
const authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

        const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });
        const nowInSeconds = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Convert current time to seconds
        if (decodedToken.payload.exp < nowInSeconds) {
            // Token has expired
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        }

        jwt.verify(token, PUB_KEY, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
            req.user = user;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
};
```

The 'const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });'
can extract the 'decodedToken.payload.exp' expires mili-seconds. So you have to divide 1000 to convert seconds and compare.

##### Test by Postman

Get Token URL

```
POST http://localhost:3000/auth/login
```

In `Tests` tab

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("test-token", jsonData.token);
console.log(pm.environment.get("test-token"));
```

[image]

In Body

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "password": "password"
}
```

[image]

Get user Infor

```
GET http://localhost:3000/info/getInfo
```

Within 60 seconds,  call API
[image]

Out of 60 seconds later , call API

[image]

---

#### Update

##### how to support logout

`Logout Request`: When a user wants to log out of the system, they send a logout request to the server. This request typically goes to a specific endpoint, such as /logout.

`Token Invalidation`: Upon receiving the logout request, the server invalidates the user's authentication token. This means that the token will no longer be accepted for making authenticated requests.

`Token Blacklisting`: To achieve token invalidation, the server maintains a list of invalidated tokens. When a user logs out, their token is added to this list, effectively blacklisting it.

And make shared variable token array cross over `/logout` (root of project) and middleware. This allows both the logout code and the authentication middleware to access and manipulate the list

in `tokenManager.js`

```js
let invalidatedTokens = [];
module.exports = {
    addToInvalidatedTokens: (token) => {
        invalidatedTokens.push(token);
    },

    isTokenInvalid: (token) => {
        return invalidatedTokens.includes(token);
    }
};
```

in `auth.js`

```js
const { addToInvalidatedTokens } = require('../auth/tokenManager');
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  addToInvalidatedTokens(token);
  res.sendStatus(200); // Respond with success
});
```

in `authMiddleware.js`

```
const { isTokenInvalid } = require('../auth/tokenManager');
const authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

        // Check if the token is in the invalidated tokens list
        if (isTokenInvalid(token)) {
            return res.sendStatus(401); // Token is invalid
        }
 ...
```

#### Needs update three files with full code

In `./src/routes/auth.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const { login } = require('../auth/authService');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { issueJWT, addToInvalidatedTokens } = require('../auth/tokenManager');

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const PUB_KEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../private/public.key'), 'utf8');

// Endpoint per il login
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
  const { username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const { token, expires, refreshToken } = login(username, password); // Aggiunto refreshToken
    res.json({
      success: true,
      token: token,
      expiresIn: expires,
      refreshToken: refreshToken // Inviato il refreshToken nella risposta
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
  }
});


// Your logout endpoint
router.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
  addToInvalidatedTokens(token);
  res.sendStatus(200); // Respond with success
});

// Endpoint per il rinnovo del token
router.post('/refreshToken', (req, res) => {
  const { refreshToken } = req.body;

  if (!refreshToken) {
    return res.status(401).json({ message: "Refresh Token richiesto" });
  }

  try {
    const payload = jwt.verify(refreshToken, PUB_KEY, { algorithms: ['RS256'] });

    // Aggiungi qui la logica per verificare che il refresh token sia ancora valido, per esempio controllando nel tuo database

    const user = { id: payload.sub }; // Assumi che tu possa ottenere l'utente in base al sub nel payload
    const newTokenObject = issueJWT(user);
    res.json({
      success: true,
      token: newTokenObject.token,
      expiresIn: newTokenObject.expires
    });

  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "Refresh Token non valido" });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

In `./src/auth/tokenManager.js`

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

let invalidatedTokens = [];

const PRIV_KEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../private/private.key'), 'utf8');

const issueJWT = (user) => {
    const expiresIn = 60; // 60 seconds
    const payload = {
        sub: user.id,
        iat: Date.now(),
        exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + expiresIn // exp is in seconds since Unix epoch
    };
    const signedToken = jwt.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, { algorithm: 'RS256' });
    return {
        token: signedToken,
        expires: expiresIn
    };
};

const issueRefreshToken = (user) => {
    const expiresIn = '7d';
    const payload = {
        sub: user.id,
        iat: Date.now(),
    };
    const refreshToken = jwt.sign(payload, PRIV_KEY, { expiresIn: expiresIn, algorithm: 'RS256' });
    return refreshToken;
};

module.exports = {
    issueJWT,
    issueRefreshToken,
    addToInvalidatedTokens: (token) => {
        invalidatedTokens.push(token);
    },

    isTokenInvalid: (token) => {
        return invalidatedTokens.includes(token);
    }
};
```

In `./src/middleware/authMiddleware.js`

```js
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { isTokenInvalid } = require('../auth/tokenManager');

const PUB_KEY = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '../../private/public.key'), 'utf8');
const authenticateJWT = (req, res, next) => {
    const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
    if (authHeader) {
        const token = authHeader.split(' ')[1];

        // Check if the token is in the invalidated tokens list
        if (isTokenInvalid(token)) {
            return res.sendStatus(401); // Token is invalid
        }

        const decodedToken = jwt.decode(token, { complete: true });
        const nowInSeconds = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000); // Convert current time to seconds
        if (decodedToken.payload.exp < nowInSeconds) {
            // Token has expired
            return res.sendStatus(401);
        }

        jwt.verify(token, PUB_KEY, { algorithms: ['RS256'] }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) return res.sendStatus(403);
            req.user = user;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        res.sendStatus(401);
    }
};

module.exports = {
    authenticateJWT,
};
```

##### How to test logout by Postman

```
POST http://localhost:3000/auth/logout
```

[image]

Will get Unauthorized after logout even if call API within 60 seconds

[image]

Comment: Can you help me with logout method? how can I implement?

Comment: @joisberg, I added `Update` part.  You can use `/logout` end point to make invalidate token. It is worth a new question item but it is an extra point to get already from Rory. So I added it here.